# Eclipse BIRT Timeline for one Day in minutes

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, birt

I am building reports with Eclipse BIRT and got to a problem with the scales of the x-axis. I am getting my input with a select-string out of a database table. There I have events from a Nagios-log-file, with timestamps for every events begin and end. Out of them I create a time like hh:mm, this is enough, it doesn't have to have the seconds or the date (These I select somewhere else). For every event I get a 1 or a 0, representing up- and downtimes.

Now I want to built the report so that I have the scaling of the x-axis for all 1440 Minutes of the day, just changing the state (to 0) when there is a downtime. I've already tried to format the scale, but it doesn't work at all. After days of searching and 'try and error' I am now asking for help. Is there a way to format the chart the way I need and how could it be done?

The last idea of mine was to have another table with every minute inculded from which I select the data and to update this table with the event-data from the nagios-log-table, but this doens't seem to be an adequate solution. Maybe there is something simple I am just not able to see right now.

P.S.: I am fairly new in this and the eclipse manual did not help me with this specific problem. I also know that there are easy, simply and amazing ways to get those kinds of report out of nagios, but I have to do it with BIRT...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to get the report the way I needed.

I am joining my data_table with "generate_series" to get the missing data for every minute.

The postgresql statement looks like:

```
  select *, coalesce(updown, 1)
    from generate_series ('19.12.2015 00:00'::timestamp, '19.12.2015 23:59', '1 minute')
    left join data_table
    on date_trunc('minute',to_timestamp(date_ts)) = generate_series
    and host like '%host%';
```

This may not be the best way to do it, but it worked for me and maybe it is also helpful for others. To usw this with BIRT I just replaced the host and the dates with the parameter-sgn "?".